# Boost thread not calling thread function

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am trying to create a boost thread and I see the thread is created but the control does not come to the thread function. Can someone please explain why is it so?

Please see below for the code used.

header_file.h

```
class fa {
public:
  fa();
  ~fa();
  int init(void);
  static void* clThreadMemFunc(void *arg) { return ((fa*)arg)->collectData((fa*)arg); }
  void* collectData(fa *f );
private:
  int m_data;
  boost::thread *m_CollectDataThread;
};
```

`

test.cpp

```
int fa::init(void)
{
     if (m_CollectDataThread== NULL)
     {
          printf("New Thread...\n");
          try 
          {
              m_CollectDataThread = 
              new boost::thread((boost::bind(&fanotify::clThreadMemFunc, this)));
          }
          catch (...){perror("Thread error ");}
          printf("m_CollectDataThread: %p \n", m_CollectDataThread);
     }
 return 0;
}
void* fa::collectData(fa *f)
{
    printf("In collectData\n");
    int data = f->m_data;
    printf("data %d",data);
}
```

The `test.cpp` is complied/built as a library (`test.so`) and another main function calls the `init` function. I see the variable `m_collectDataThread` value changing from null to some value (thread gets created) and also catch does not get any exception.

But I don't see any statement in `collectData` getting printed. Why is the thread not able to reach it?

Comment: Maybe you should wait for the thread to finish? Or even start?

Comment: _`if (m_CollectDataThread== NULL)`_ Any piece of code available, where you actually initialised `m_CollectDataThread` with `NULL`?

Comment: @Alan How to ensure that the thread is started?

Comment: m_CollectDataThread is initialized in constructor, sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: The `join` achieves both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try adding a join.

E.g.

```
 try 
      {
          m_CollectDataThread = 
          new boost::thread(boost::bind(&fanotify::clThreadMemFunc, this));
           m_CollectDataThread->join();    
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `boost::thread` or `std::thread` you do not need old way of passing thread function (using static method and casting `void *` pointer), you can call class method directly:

```
class fa {
public:
  fa();
  ~fa();
  int init(void);
  void collectData();
private:
  int m_data;
  boost::thread *m_CollectDataThread;
};

m_CollectDataThread = new boost::thread( &fa::collectData, this );
// or explicitly using bind
m_CollectDataThread = new boost::thread( boost::bind( &fa::collectData, this ) );
```

boost is C++ library, not C